# Encode NSMutableArray partially with NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, objective-c, serialization

I have my *Person* class which implements *NSCoding* protocol:

```
@interface Person : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property NSString *name;
@property float salary;
@end

@implementation Person
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{

    [aCoder encodeObject:_name forKey:@"name"];
    [aCoder encodeFloat:_salary forKey:@"salary"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if(self=[super init])
    {
        _name =[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
        _salary=[aDecoder decodeFloatForKey:@"salary"];
    }
    return self;

}
```

Also I have an array with persons, which I want to serialize. But not all the entities. I want to save it partially. I decided to create my own subclass of *NSMutableArray* which will implement *NSCoding* protocol and it's own *encodeWithCoder* and *initWithCoder* methods:

```
@interface customNSMutableArray : NSMutableArray<NSCoding>
@end

@implementation customNSMutableArray

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    for(NSObject * obj in self)
    {
        //if(some_condition) 
          [aCoder encodeObject:obj];
    }

}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    //@todo
    return self;
}

@end
```

And here is a trouble. After trying to encode my *customNSMutableArray*:

```
@property customNSMutableArray   *companyStaff;
...
NSData * data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_companyStaff];
```

The *encodeWithCoder* method in my *customNSMutableArray* is not invoked.
It's directly passed to *encodeWithCoder* of my *Person* entities within the array.

How can I serialize NSMutableArray partially?

Comment: It's not a good idea to subclass `NSMutableArray`. It's part of a "class cluster". And there's no reason to subclass it anyway for this. Just archive/unarchive the whole `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `Person` into `PartialPerson`, which you can archive/unarchive.

It's not a good idea to subclass NSMutableArray, and I see no reason for doing so.

Comment: Hmm.. I dont understand how it will help for me. I have a NSMutableArray with some Persons. The only way I see it's create a partial copy of NSMutableArray and save it. But it needs additional RAM to duplicate  Person entities (or not?).